# Yii - how to override/extend core file

Tags: yii, overriding

I need to override some yii core files - specifically, CGridColumn.php and CController.php.  I need to make sure that these classes are referenced in my application instead of the core files that they override or extend.  How do I do this?  It's got to be pretty simple but I can't seem to find a documented 'correct' way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to extend base controller:

1. Create Controller.php in your protected/components directory:

   ```
   class Controller extends CController
       {
       public $newProperty;

       public function newMethod()
       {
       ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Make sure Controller.php is imported in config:

   ```
   'import' => array(
       ...
       'application.components.Controller',
       ...
   ),
   ```
3. Extend your controllers from Controller, not CController:

   ```
   class ExampleController extends Controller {
       ...
   }
   ```

If you want to extend CGridColumn, 1 and 2 steps are the same, but in your custom class don't forget to import original class:

```
    Yii::import('zii.widgets.grid.CGridColumn');

    class TestColumn extends CGridColumn
    {
        ...
    }
```

And then just use it in columns array of CGridView

```
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'class' => 'TestColumn',
        ),  
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks Choo, I figured out as much after I had some dinner but this surely helps.  Thank you for documenting it so cleanly :)

Answer (score 2):

**Extending common classes to allow better customization**

> http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/121/extending-common-classes-to-allow-better-customization/

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, I don't know how I missed that article.